# Integer partitions and permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, integer-partitions, permutation-cycles

I am given the pair $(n, \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$ such that 6 is not a part in $\lambda$.  I am told to let $\lambda^*$ represent the partition of $n$ conjugate to $\lambda$.  Now we are supposing $(n, \lambda)$ has the following property: there exists a $\theta \in S_n$, the set of permutations of $\{1,2, \dots, n\}$, and $\theta^* \in S_n$ such that both $\theta, \theta^*$ have order 6, $\theta$ has cycle-structure $\lambda$, and $\theta^*$ has cycle-structure $\lambda^*$.  I am asked to determine the possible values of n.  I am not sure where to start here.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the partition must consist of some parts of size $2$ and $3$ (in order for the associated permutation to have order $6$), it could also have some parts of size $1$.

The dual partition is obtained by reflecting in the diagonal, & this tableau will need to only have parts of size $1,2,3$ or $6$ (If it does not have $6$, then it must have at least one $2$ and $3$ (in order for the associated permutation to have order $6$)).

What shapes are possible ?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the overall shapes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. ... I guess so.

Comment: Haha I didn't understand your reference to "what shapes are possible." I guess we are both a tad bit confused.

Comment: I bet the confusion is about identifying partitions with shapes of tableaux.  Then there's also whether you draw partitions/tableaux the "French" way (as here) or the "English" way (parts correspond to rows, largest at the top).

Comment: I have $4$ possible solutions written in my note book ... but there could be more ... let me know what you think.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Lol, I am English, but I use the French convention for my Young Teableaux.

Comment: Maybe I am dumb, but why wouldn't it just be 6 and multiples of 6?

Comment: That would make the associated order of the permutation larger then $6$.

Comment: Okay, then I might need a bit more of a hint as to how to go about doing this.

Comment: Right o ... I have $5$ solutions & I believe that is the lot. What possibilities have you found? ... might be an idea to go to a chat room ?

Comment: Yea that works I just realized today that I could do that, but the website asked me if I would like to join a chat room.  Do you know how to initialize a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101861/discussion-between-donald-splutterwit-and-ethan-deakins).